# Bernoulli trials $X_1 , X_2 , X_3 , \ldots$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a sequence of Bernoulli trials $X_1 , X_2 , X_3 , \ldots$, where $X_n = 1$ or $0$.

If we suppose that $$\Pr\{X_n=1\mid X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{n-1}\} \geq \alpha > 0, \ n=1,2,\ldots $$

Could someone help me to prove that:

$$\Pr\{X_n=1 \text{ for some } n \}= 1 \text{ and } \Pr\{X_n=1 \text{ infinitely often } n \}= 1 $$

A Bernoulli trial results only in 1 or 0. It takes the trials of only the happening or non happening of any event.

I've been super stuck on this question for a while now. Would really appreciate it if someone could break down the solution for me or give me hints.

Thanks for your hints, help and time.

Comment: Note the use of \text{} and \mid and \Pr in my edits to this question. $\qquad$

Comment: Doesn't the second imply the first one?

Comment: I´m really stuck in this problem, I do not know how start it, but yes I think we can prove the first and the use that for prove the second.

Comment: If $\mu^*$ is an outer measure on $X$, the collection $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mu^*$-measurable sets is a &sigma;-algebra and the restriction of $\mu^*$ to $\mathcal{M}$ is a complete measure. But I do not understand the connection with the problem?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\Pr(X_{k+1}=0,\ldots,X_{k+n}=0) &= \Pr(\Pr(X_{k+1}=0,\ldots,X_{k+n}=0\mid X_1,\ldots,X_k))\\
&=\Pr(\Pr(X_{k+n}=0\mid X_1,\ldots,X_k, X_{k+1}=0,\ldots,X_{k+n-1}=0)\cdot \Pr(X_{k+1}=0,\ldots,X_{k+n-1}=0\mid X_1,\ldots,X_k))\\
&\le (1-\alpha)\Pr(\Pr(X_{k+1}=0,\ldots,X_{k+n-1}=0\mid X_1,\ldots,X_k))\\
\end{align}
and continuing by induction $\Pr(X_{k+1}=0,\ldots,X_{k+n}=0)\le (1-\alpha)^n$ for any $k$. Letting $n\to\infty,$ $\Pr(X_n=0:n\ge k)=0$ for any $k$, so
$$
\Pr(X=0 \text{ eventually})\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty\Pr(X_n=0:n\ge k)\le 0,
$$
so $X_n$ is $1$ infinitely often.

Comment: $ \Pr\{X_n=1 \text{ infinitely often } n \}= 1 $ implies $\Pr\{X_n=1 \text{ for some } n \}= 1$ ?